# flex combobox customize problem

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, air, adobe, stack-overflow

I'm new to flex and i need to create item and subitems in combobox, where only subitem is  clickable. 
similar to what is shown in the given link as under:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/25/creating-a-custom-combobox-item-renderer-in-flex/
but here both header and option are clicked at the same time whereas i need that only option should be clickable
Is there any way to do the same.
PLease help.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The combobox that you want is just a normal combobox only the items are visually different.

So when you get the data inside your itemRenderer with:

```
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value; 
                if (data.isChild == false){
                    this.mainLabel.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                }else if (data.isChild == true){
                    this.mainLabel.setStyle("fontWeight","normal");
                }
        }
```

You call a function that checks if a boolean in that data is true or false. If it is false a Label is bold. If trueLabel is normal.

But for this solution you have to have access to the data that you get.

Comment: thanx for comment Arno but this is not something which i'm looking for actually i need to create submenus in combobox where the header option should not be clickable.